# VBA: loop losing variable value

Tags: vba, loops, variables

I've got a strange problem with a loop in VBA, as it seems to be losing the value of my variable. Any ideas why? If i delete the loop, debug.print shows "test", otherwise it's empty (unless I print the value of "dupa" inside the loop)... Seems very strange.

```
Function carbon_copy(indeks As String) As String

Dim emails(1 To 3) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim dupa As String

emails(1) = "abc@wp.pl"
emails(2) = "pabc@wp.pl"
emails(3) = "rabc@wp.pl"

i = 1
dupa = "test"

Do While emails(i) <> ""

    If i = indeks Then
         GoTo NextIteration
    End If

    dupa = dupa & ";" & emails(i)


    NextIteration:
    i = i + 1

Loop

Debug.Print dupa

carbon_copy = dupa

End Function
```

Comment: Does it work if you add an `emails(4)` with a value of `""` (and change to `Dim emails(1 To 4) As String`)?

Comment: Yeah, it does indeed. All clear now, stupid mistake, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in the code? Ignoring an error with that (such as trying to access an array element which doesn't exist) *could* give unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're indexing out of the array bounds. The condition `Do While emails(i) <> ""` is always true given your array, so the this fails on `emails(4)`. Just test the array bounds and loop over that:

```
For i = LBound(emails) To UBound(emails)
    If emails(i) <> "" And i = indeks Then
        dupa = dupa & ";" & emails(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Either `Do While emails(i) <> ""` is always true, and then it's an useless check, or it is not and then the loop doesn't exit upon first empty string (as OP's intent seems to be).

Comment: @DisplayName Both true. I didn't attempt to match what the OP intended to do, because I have no clue what the intended output of the function was. This was simply showing the loop with the `While` test inside.

Answer (score 2):

You should get a runtime error 9 since you index `i` will be 4 after you looped through your emails String array. As soon as it tries to compare the value of `emails(4)` with `""` it should produce the "index out of range" since you have defined your Array to be only 3 elements long.

For a little clarification try this example code, it should produce the same error:

```
Function littleTest()
    Dim teststr(1 To 3) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    teststr(1) = "abc"
    teststr(2) = "def"
    teststr(3) = "ghi"

    i = 1

    Do While teststr(i) <> ""
        Debug.Print "i do it for the " & i & " time!"
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

You have already found the solution yourself since `UBound()` is returning the actual length of your array which is in your case three so it will never search beyond the array.

Comment: Yes, that's what it should do. He has already found the actual solution himself but by giving him an example of a little more simple code which results in the same error I hoped to make it easier for him to understand what his error was about.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've already solved the problem by using other loop type (For i = 1 To UBound(emails), Next i), but why the previous loop did not work is still quite mysterious to me... If anyone can explain, I'd appreciate it, as I prefer to understand things rather thank just do them correctly.

W.

Answer (score 0):

this should work (explanations in comments):

```
Function carbon_copy(indeks As Long) As String
    Dim emails(1 To 3) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dupa As String

    emails(1) = "abc@wp.pl"
    emails(2) = "pabc@wp.pl"
    emails(3) = "rabc@wp.pl"

    i = 1
    Do While emails(i) <> ""
        If i <> indeks Then dupa = dupa & ";" & emails(i) ' update 'dupa' if current index doesn't natch passed 'indeks'
        i = i + 1
        If i > UBound(emails, 1) Then Exit Do ' be sure to exit upon exceeding 'emails()' array size
    Loop

    carbon_copy = dupa
End Function
```